# Testing async function with Vue Jest doesnt work

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Function:
(Update: Because of the other code I need it to be async/await, otherwise my other code doesn't work)

```
 async getAll() {
            request_url = "http://localhost:8082/test"
            await axios
                .get(request_url, {
                    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
                })
                .then(response => {
                    this.all= response.data
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errorMessage = error.message
                })
        },
```

Test:

```
import { mount, shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Map from '@/views/Map'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import moxios from 'moxios'
import axios from 'axios'
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises'
jest.mock('axios');

Vue.use(Vuetify)
let vuetify
let wrapper
vuetify = new Vuetify()
const localVue = createLocalVue()


describe('View', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();

        moxios.install()
        wrapper = shallowMount(Map, {
            localVue,
            vuetify,
        })
       // I need this because I call another function with axios on mounted
        flushPromises()
        
    })
 

     it('should get all', async () => {

        axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
            data: [
                {
                    test: 'test'
                }
            ]
          }); 
        
        await wrapper.vm.getAll().then(() => {
            expect(wrapper.vm.all).toEqual(
                 test: 'test'
            )

    }) 
})
```

Result:

```
 Expected value to equal:
      {"test": "test"}
    Received:
      undefined
```

I've tried with promises, with moxios, with sinon, nothing seems to work. When I log the `this.all` in the function, it has the correct value. However, in the test it doesn't wait for the function to finish and for the value to be assigned to `this.all`. I tried with `nextTick`, with `flushPromises`, with `await`. How do I make the test wait until the function `getAll()` has assigned `this.all` the response data? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't the flush supposed to happen after you've mocked the call?

Comment: the flush in before is for my an async function in mounted(), but i also tried adding flush before and after I call getall()

Answer (score 0):

Your method getAll() should be a promise, because "axios" is and returns a promise.

So.. if getAll is a promise, you can call it next with .then().catch()..

Remember return in your promise the resolve() when everyting the tasks ends, or rejection() if your promise ends with errors.